# materialized view - Why do we need it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read this article...
http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/materialized-view-strategies-using-postgresql

the auther says:

> A materialized view is a snapshot of a query saved into a table.

If that is the case, why do we need materialized view?
How is it diffrent than insert to table from query:

```
insert into items_ver(item_id, item_group, name)
select * from items where item_id=2;
```

Comment: They are used for performance reasons. The idea being that the query in question would be too slow to run on demand, so the results of that query are periodically saved to a table for quicker access. Materialized Views are often used in data warehousing scenarios.

Comment: It's not that different, but it provides you a richer and nicer interface. With a simple insert, you get to do all the details of deleting/updating etc. yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Materialized View versus Regular View:

- A regular view is a stored query that is ready for use. However, it is run every time you query the view. This can make complex queries simpler, but you take the performance hit of the view's query every time you run it.
- A materialized view not only pre-runs the results of a query for you. You can actually index the results, to optimize what is effectively subqueries of the view. In this way, you can get many of the benefits of both a physical table and a view.
- The downside, to a materialized view is that you need to actively instruct it to update its contents, which is why (as the commenter pointed out) it is most effective for data warehouses versus active transactional databases where you might expect the contents to always be up-to-date.

Materialized View versus Actual Table:

- An actual table can be populated by a query, but it is no longer bound to the query that populated it. You can, for example, insert elements into it that the query would not return.
- A materialized view remains bound to the query that created it. You can re-populate it with the latest results of the query by calling `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW {view_name}`.